# Electron build generating wrong index.html & renderer.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

My electron app is working properly in dev mode(`yarn run start`). But, when I'm trying to build the app by using "`yarn dist`" command it's processing without any issue. But, when click on the setup file & open the app I can see it's pointing to the wrong `index.html & renderer.js`. Because of this, I'm getting following error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**The folder structure of my app is like this -**

[image]

**My `package.json` file structure is -**

```
{
  "name": "electron-webpack-quick-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": {
    "name": "Suresh",
    "email": "suresh@gmail.com",
    "url": "https://example.com"
  },
  "main": "main.js",
  "description": "Test App",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "electron-webpack dev",
    "compile": "electron-webpack",
    "dist": "yarn compile && electron-builder",
    "dist:dir": "yarn dist --dir -c.compression=store -c.mac.identity=null",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "start": "electron .",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^22.0.3",
    "electron-builder": "^22.4.1",
    "electron-webpack": "^2.8.2",
    "webpack": "~4.42.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.example.app",
    "files": [
      "package.json",
      "main.js",
      "preload.js",
      "renderer.js",
      "index.html",
      "node_modules",
      "main.exe"
    ],
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    },
    "dmg": {
      "background": null,
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
      "window": {
        "width": "400",
        "height": "300"
      },
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 100
        },
        {
          "x": 300,
          "y": 100,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": "dmg",
      "category": "public.app-category.utilities"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": "AppImage",
      "category": "Utility"
    }
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'"
    />
    <meta
      http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'"
    />
    <title>Hello from Electron renderer!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello from Electron renderer!</h1>
    <p></p>
    <p id="info"></p>
  </body>
  <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const { exec } = require('child_process')

const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1000,
        height: 700,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true
        },
    });

    win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    let backend;
    backend = path.join(process.cwd(), 'main.exe')
    var execfile = require('child_process').execFile;
    execfile(
        backend,
        {
            windowsHide: true,
        }, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('1.Flask Server Error: ', err);
            } if (stdout) {
                console.log('Flask Server Started: ', stdout);
            } if (stderr) {
                console.log('2.Flask Server Error: ', stderr);
            }
        }
    )

    createWindow();

    app.on('activate', () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow();
        }
    });
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    exec('taskkill /f /t /im main.exe', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('taskkill error: ', err)
            return;
        }

        console.log('stdout: ', stdout)
        console.log('stderr: ', stderr)
    });

    console.log('application gogin to close...')
    console.log('process.platform: ', process.platform)

    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});
```

**preload.js**

```
const { contextBridge } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('versions', {
    node: () => process.versions.node,
    chrome: () => process.versions.chrome,
    electron: () => process.versions.electron,
    // we can also expose variables, not just functions
})
```

**renderer.js**

```
const information = document.getElementById('info')
information.innerText = `This app is using Chrome (v${versions.chrome()}), Node.js (v${versions.node()}), and Electron (v${versions.electron()})`


function pingServer() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((text) => {
            console.log('Server message: ', text);
            setText("server_msg", text)
        });
}

function setText(id, newvalue) {
    var s = document.getElementById(id);
    s.innerHTML = newvalue;
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Need some help fig. this out.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I worked through this while developing cross-platform with electron-builder.

The issue is with on Intel Mac and Windows, the files and folders are in different directories compared to in dev mode.

While I can't tell you how to fix it directly, it's just a matter of getting the relative imports correct, which you can see by comparing things with what's in the win-unpacked folder.

But you can use something like:

`var isDev = process.env.APP_DEV ? (process.env.APP_DEV.trim() == "true") : false;`
In your various javascript and html.
And
`APP_DEV=true` in your `npm run start` or `electron .` or as you've said `yarn run start` (as in put it in your packages.json under the `start` script.

EDIT: To clarify, to check, look through win-unpacked directory, and you'll see that your `__dirname` may need to be something else.

For me I use `var dirname = path.join(process.resourcesPath, '..');` on windows, and then replace `__dirname` with `dirname`

Comment: When I print ```var dirname = path.join(process.resourcesPath, '..');``` & ```__dirname``` it's looks like this - ```__dirname:  C:\Users\SMajhi2\Documents\Projects\Electron\electron-webpack-quick-start, dirname:  C:\Users\SMajhi2\Documents\Projects\Electron\electron-webpack-quick-start\node_modules\electron\dist```. If I replace ```__dirname``` with ```dirname``` then I'm getting error like ```Unable to load preload script: C:\Users\SMajhi2\Documents\Projects\Electron\electron-webpack-quick-start\node_modules\electron\dist\preload.js```. This error, I can understand why I'm getting.

Comment: Is that on start or dist?